# Globally defining rules for common request fields

Tags: laravel, validation

In my Laravel 5.7 application I have several requests that collect common information - name, email, phone, etc.

Is there an efficient manner to define the validation rules for these common or "global" fields at the application level as apposed to the request level so that they can be better managed?

Currently, updating the validation means touching every request.

Short of creating rules for each field and importing them at the head of each request, I don't see an elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a middleware to achieve that : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

I don't have an exemple but i think doing something like this can work :

First create a middleware :

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckCommonFields
```

Then verify if your request contains "common request fields"

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->input('email')) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('somewhere')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
        }
    } 

    return $next($request);
}
```

Add the middleware to your Kernel.php `$routeMiddleware` :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'commonFields' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckCommonFields::class,
    ];
```

Finally, add the middleware for the route concerned by theses validation rules in web.php (or api.php or whatever.php) :

```
Route::post(/whatever/you/want, 'WhateverController@action')->name('whatever')->middleware('commonFields');
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate this. I will check it out in dev and follow up / mark this as answered. Thank you.

Comment: Louis any reason to duplicate the validator fail logic for each request field check?  Violating DRY makes my skin crawl.

Comment: i just gave you a way to do that you can do whatever you want in the middleware

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope this is what you're looking for, apologies if not.

For common validation I create a Requests form - [Laravel docs - HTTP requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests)

If you use something like `php artisan make:request ExampleFormRequest`this will create the relevant folder 'Requests' within the Http folder.

Within your file ExampleFormRequest you can specify rules, and then instead of validating the same thing multiple times in your controller

e.g.

```
    'name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'address' => 'required|string|max:500'
```

etc, you can just call in the Request form in the Methods argument like so:

```
public function store(ExampleFormRequest $request)
{
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: this is the common way. I think he doesn't want to do that for each request

Comment: Correct, I am already using requests for all my, well, requests, but they all contain common fields that I'd like to abstract out to make managing them, or adding to them, easier.

Comment: I agree, this is the common way - but what about combining this with your own config or defined constants?  After all, we're basically dealing with strings here.  Or maybe your hoping  for some kind of ... global request validator?

Comment: @ironchefbadass What's wrong with using a middleware ?

Comment: @louis I'm not apposed to exploring it if there is an example you'd care to share. I was not aware middleware could be used in this manner. Always open to learning something new

Comment: @LouisR Ahh okay, I see. Thanks for clarifying. Probably best just to use middleware